# Necessary and sufficient condition for two different metrics $d, d'$ to generate the same topology on $M$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I would like to show the following result :

> Suppose M is a set and $d, d'$ are two different metrics. Prove that $d$ and $d'$ generate the same topology on M iff for every $x \in M$, for every $r > 0$, there exist positive numbers $r_1, r_2$ such that $B^{(d)}_{r_1}(x) \subset B^{(d')}_{r}(x)$ and $B^{(d')}_{r_2}(x) \subset B^{(d)}_{r}(x)$.

My attempt : 
Consider the identity function $f : (M, d) \to (M, d')$. $d$ and $d'$ generate the same topology is equivalent to the fact that the pre-image by $f$ of every open subset of $(M, d')$ is also open (since $f$ is the identity function). Using the Open Subset Criterion for Continuity, we can say that $f$ is continuous. Therefore, using the definition of continuity, for any $r > 0$, there exists $r_1 > 0$ such that $B^{(d)}_{r_1} \subset B^{(d')}_{r}$. We do the same with the function $f' : (M, d') \to (M, d)$, and since there are equivalences everywhere, both implication and reciprocal are true.

Since topology is new to me, I wanted to make sure that this is correct. Also, I wonder if there aren't faster/simpler methods.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very elegant proof in how it wields the definition of continuity to its advantage, and it is probably as fast as any other method anyone could suggest.

It is perhaps not the simplest. Here is the most obvious proof (for me).

---

Let $\tau, \tau'$ denote the topologies induced by $d,d'$ respectively.

Suppose that $U \in \tau$ is a $d$-open set, and let $x \in U$. Then, there exists $r > 0$ such that $B^{(d)}_r(x) \subseteq U$. By assumption, there exists $r_2 > 0$ such that $B^{(d')}_{r_2} (x) \subseteq U$. Observe that:

$$ U = \bigcup_{x \in U} B^{(d')}_{r_2}(x) $$

This is a union of $d'$-open sets, so $U$ is $d'$-open i.e. $U \in \tau'$. But $U$ was arbitrary, so $\tau \subseteq \tau'$.

By symmetry, $\tau' \subseteq \tau$. Hence, $\tau = \tau'$.

---

This proof is perhaps more natural, as it uses the valuable intuition that open sets are neighbourhoods of all of their points; this concept is also very helpful when the objects of study are general topological spaces.

But your reasoning is perfectly fine -- well done.

Comment: Thank you! I like your proof because it's simpler and it's easy to understand what we are doing!